# Gitlab CI connection refused on elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to connect elasticsearch on Gitlab CI for running my test but always got connection refused

here my script

```
services:
      - name: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0          
        command: [ "bin/elasticsearch", "-Expack.security.enabled=false", "-Ediscovery.type=single-node" ]
script:
      - curl "http://$(cat /etc/hosts |grep $HOSTNAME|cut -d$'\t' -f1):9200"
```

Wtih `$(cat /etc/hosts |grep $HOSTNAME|cut -d$'\t' -f1)` I can get IP address

I try to use `alias: elasticsearch` but when I `curl "http://elasticsearch:9200"` also got error `Could not resolve host`

Comment: Try to use sleep in the script and connect to the executor. Try to check if Elasticsearch is available from inside the container

Comment: Thank you very much. I added `sleep 30` and it's work.

Comment: Ah. I thought that sleep will help you debug the issue but if it works :)